# Backup Oracle Data Guard with TDPO

Tags: oracle, backup, dataguard

We are using TSM/TDPO SBT to backup Oracle Databases. When using Oracle Data Guard with TDPO, what is the best strategy to ensure backups continue after failover/switchover? 
TSM/TDPO uses a feature called datamove which makes sure that backups from primary and standby are moved to one TSM node. (TSM node A (primary) and B (standby) move there Backups to C. Restore will use C).
The RMAN scripts called by TDPO need a logic to prevent backups are taken from both (primary and standby). This could be done by querying the role of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using Oracle Data Guard with TDPO, what is the best strategy to
>   ensure backups continue after failover/switchover?

Use RMAN catalog, because without a catalog, backups taken on one site do not appear in the controlfile of the database on the other site. You need a centralized catalog for backups in a Data Guard configuration.

Use role-based services, and TNS entries with connect-time failover, using these services. Use these TNS entries for logging in to the database when performing backups. This way you always log in to the primary/standby database, and you do not need to check for the role of the database.

> TSM/TDPO uses a feature called datamove which makes sure that backups
>   from primary and standby are moved to one TSM node. (TSM node A
>   (primary) and B (standby) move there Backups to C. Restore will use
>   C).

The database/RMAN layer has nothing to do with. Just configure TSM and TDPO properly, and this will be transparent for the database, always using the same `tdpo.opt` file.

> The RMAN scripts called by TDPO need a logic to prevent backups are
>   taken from both (primary and standby). This could be done by querying
>   the role of the database.

No, see above, role-based services, connect-time failover TNS entries.